# is it possible to automatically drag and drop on click event from one group list to another angular cdk

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

i have a list of items one is available items and another is selected item so
in available item there is input field for set quantity after filling quantity information on keyword enter press it need to move on selected items list. I have already implemented drag and drop but it need to transfer from one group list to another group list on enter(keyup) event.
[image: available items with quantity input field]

[image: selected item]

Comment: I mean.. in cdkDragDrop, you only transfer an item from one array to the other array.. you can easily do that using a click handler as well right?

Comment: it doesn't work by handling click event. i will not get proper data on click to call transferArrayItem method to change there group @MikeOne

Comment: Yeah, you can’t call your drop handler.. you just have to make a click handler that moves the item from array 1 to array 2. If you have setup your loops to create the draggables correctly, the item will just disappear from the container and appear in the other one. That is the same thing as transferArrayItem does..